# How to confirm that FileReader doesn't refresh/reload the react page ( even using with e.preventDefault();)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sharp

I am trying to upload an image to my nodejs api/service using FileReader, the file is uploaded successfully but the page gets reloaded.

```
// html part
 import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { withRouter, useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Page from "./Page";
import TitleBar from "./TitleBar";
import SingleGalleryRow from "./SingleGalleryRow";
import CenteredPopup from "../common/CenteredPopup";
import { MdDelete,MdOutlineCrop,MdOutlineCircle } from "react-icons/md";
import Cropper from "react-easy-crop";

import getCroppedImg from "../shared/util/cropImage";

function EditImage{breadcrumb,pageName,setLoader,showToast}) {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const history = useHistory();
    //const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const [umodalShow, setUModalShow] = useState(false);
    const [row, setRow] = useState({
        ImageName: "",
        ImageServerPath: "",
        ImageFullUrl: "",
        ImageUrl: "",
        SiteId: 1,
        CreatedBy: 1,
        CreatedOn: "",
        Id: 0,
        Name: "",
        IsDeleted: 0,
        IsVisible: 1,
        ModifiedBy: 1,
        ModifiedOn: "",
    });
    const [isSubmitClicked, setIsSubmitClicked] = useState(false);
    const [IsDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [nameError, setNameError] = useState("");
    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(0);
    const { id } = useParams();
    let content = "";
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState({
        Content: "",
        CreatedBy: 1,
        CreatedOn: "",
        Id: 0,
        IsDeleted: 0,
        IsVisible: 1,
        ModifiedBy: 1,
        ModifiedOn: "",
        Name: "",
        SiteId: 1,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let abortController = new AbortController();
        //let isComponentMounted = true;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            // debugger;
            try {
                setLoader(true);
                let apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_IMAGEGALLERYAPI + "/getbyId/" + id;
                const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
                    signal: abortController.signal,
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                const resultPages = json ? json.list : "";
                if (resultPages && resultPages.length > 0) {
                    //debugger;
                    let firstRow = resultPages[0];
                    let isEnabled = false;
                    if (firstRow.IsVisible === 1 || firstRow.IsVisible === true) {
                        isEnabled = true;
                    }

                    let newDetailPage = {
                        Id: firstRow.Id,
                        Name: firstRow.Name,
                        Content: firstRow.Content,
                        IsVisible: isEnabled,
                        IsDeleted: firstRow.IsDeleted,
                        SiteId: firstRow.SiteId,
                        CreatedBy: firstRow.CreatedBy,
                        CreatedOn: firstRow.CreatedOn,
                        ModifiedBy: firstRow.ModifiedBy,
                        ModifiedOn: firstRow.ModifiedOn,
                    };
                    setDetail(newDetailPage);

                    let itemRows = [];
                    for (let item of resultPages) {
                        let row = {
                            Id: item.DetailId,
                            ImageSliderId: item.ImageSliderId,
                            ImageName: item.ImageName,
                            ImageServerPath: item.ImageServerPath,
                            ImageFullUrl: item.ImageFullUrl,
                            ImageUrl: item.ImageUrl,
                            ImageType: item.ImageType,
                            ImageSize: item.ImageSize,
                            IsVisible: item.DetIsVisible,
                            IsDeleted: item.DetIsDeleted,
                            SiteId: item.DetSiteId,
                            CreatedBy: item.DetCreatedBy,
                            CreatedOn: item.DetCreatedOn,
                            ModifiedBy: item.DetModifiedBy,
                            ModifiedOn: item.DetModifiedOn,
                        };
                        if (item.ImageFullUrl) {
                            itemRows.push(row);
                        }
                    }
                    if (itemRows && itemRows.length > 0) {
                        setList(itemRows);
                    }
                }
                setLoader(false);
                //abortController = null;
            } catch (err) {
                setLoader(false);
                if (err.name === "AbortError") {
                    // Handling error thrown by aborting request
                }
            }
        };
        fetchData();
        // Side-effect logic...
        return () => {
            // Side-effect cleanup
            abortController.abort();
            console.log("unmounting...");
        };
    }, []);

    const [imageCropWidth, setImageCropWidth] = useState(100);
    const [imageCropHeight, setImageCropHeight] = useState(100);

    const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);        
    const [aspect, setAspect] = useState(1);
    const [croppedAreaPixels, setCroppedAreaPixels] = useState(null);
    const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);
    const [cropSize, setCropSize] = useState({ width: 100, height: 100 });
    const [Image, setImage] = useState("");
    const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0);
    const [cropShape,setCropShape] = useState('rect');  
   

    const onSaveImage = async (e) => {
        //debugger;
        if (validate() < 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(Image, croppedAreaPixels, rotation);
            setCroppedImage(croppedImage);
            setImage(croppedImage);
            if (row) {
                row.ImageFullUrl = croppedImage;
            }          
        } catch (err) {
            setLoader(false);
            showToast("Error!", "Password couldn't be saved");
        } finally {
            setUModalShow(false);
        }
    };

    const showImageForCrop = (e) => {
        //debugger;
        let localSrc = e.ImageFullUrl; //e.target.src;
        setImage(localSrc);        
        setUModalShow(true);
        setCropSize({width:(imageCropWidth ? parseInt(imageCropWidth):0),
            height:(imageCropHeight ? parseInt(imageCropHeight):0)});
        if (list && list.length > 0) {
            const selectedIndex = list.findIndex((item) => item.Id === e.Id);
            if (selectedIndex > -1) {
                setRow(list[selectedIndex]);
            }
        }
    };    

  const singlefileSelectedHandler = (e) => {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDisabled(true);
        content = "";
        if (detail && detail.Content) {
            content = detail.Content;
        }
        //let imageList = "";
        const selectedImage = e.target.files[0];
        let imageSizeInMBs = selectedImage.size ? selectedImage.size / 1024 / 1024 : 0;
        if (selectedImage && imageSizeInMBs > 8) {
            setIsDisabled(false);
            setRow({
                ...row,
                ["ImageName"]: "",
                ["ImageServerPath"]: "",
                ["ImageFullUrl"]: "",
                ["ImageUrl"]: "",
            });
            showToast("Information!", "Image size can't be greater than 8MB.");
            return -1;
        }
        //setFiles(...e.target.files);
        const filename =
            selectedImage && selectedImage.name
                ? new Date().valueOf() +
                  "_" +
                  selectedImage.name.replace(/\\/g, "").replace(/ /g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "").replace(/`/g, "")
                : "";       
        debugger;
        setUModalShow(false);
        setCropSize({width:(imageCropWidth ? parseInt(imageCropWidth):0),
             height:(imageCropHeight ? parseInt(imageCropHeight):0)});
        const reader = new FileReader();       
        reader.onload = (ev) => {
            //debugger;
            ev.preventDefault();
            let base64 = ev.target.result;
            base64 = base64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");
            setImage(reader.result);            
            //imgRef.current = e.target.result;
            try {
                //debugger;
                const settings = {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        image: base64,
                        filename: filename,
                    }),
                    //signal: abortController.signal,
                };
                //setUModalShow(true); 
                fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN + `/uploaddetail`, settings)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((response) => {
                        debugger;
                        //const uploadedImageUrl = response.data.url; // get saved image url
                        const uploadedImageUrl = response.fullurl; // get saved image url
                        const uploadedImageName = response.imagename;
                        const uploadedServerPath = response.serverpath;
                        const uploadurl = response.url;
                        setRow({
                            ...row,
                            ["ImageName"]: uploadedImageName,
                            ["ImageServerPath"]: uploadedServerPath,
                            ["ImageFullUrl"]: uploadedImageUrl,
                            ["ImageUrl"]: uploadurl,
                        });
                        if (uploadedImageUrl) {
                            setIsDisabled(false);
                        }
                        content +=
                            "<div class='slide'><div class='slider-image embed-responsive-16by9' style='background-image: url(" +
                            'http://localhost:3001/' +  uploadedImageUrl +
                            ");'></div></div>";
                        setDetail({ ...detail, ["Content"]: content });
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        debugger;
                        console.log(e);
                        setIsDisabled(false);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                debugger;
                setIsDisabled(false);
            }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
               
    };

    const validate = () => {
        //debugger;
        if (detail && !detail.Name) {
            setNameError("Name is mandatory.");
            return -1;
        }
        setNameError("");
        return 0;
    };

    const HandleSaveMenu = async (e) => {
        //debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = e.currentTarget;
        if (validate() < 0) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            return -1;
        }
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const validationMessages = Array.from(formData.keys()).reduce((acc, key) => {
                acc[key] = form.elements[key].validationMessage;
                return acc;
            }, {});
            alert(validationMessages);
            //console.log(validationMessages)
        } else if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
            //setIsSubmitClicked(true);
            //debugger;
            content = `<div class="grid"><div class="grid-sizer"></div>`;
            if (list && list.length > 0) {
                //debugger;
                let listcounter = 0;
                for (let item of list) {
                    content += `<div class="grid-item"><img src="${item.ImageFullUrl}" alt="${item.ImageName}" /></div>`;
                }
                content += `</div>`;
                setDetail({ ...detail, ["Content"]: content });
            }

            //debugger;

            const settings = {
                method: "PATCH",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: detail.Name,
                    content: content /*detail.Content*/,
                    imageDetail: list,
                    siteId: 1,
                    isVisible: detail.IsVisible === true ? 1 : 0,
                    isDeleted: false,
                    CreatedBy: 1,
                    ModifiedBy: 1,
                }),
            };
            try {
                setLoader(true);
                let submitUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_IMAGEGALLERYAPI + "/" + id;
                const fetchResponse = await fetch(submitUrl, settings);
                if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
                    // => false
                    //const statusCode = fetchResponse.status; // => 404
                    const text = await fetchResponse.text();
                    //console.log(text);
                }
                const retdata = await fetchResponse.json();
                let resultSet = retdata ? retdata.list : "";
                setLoader(false);
                if (resultSet && resultSet.length > 0 && resultSet[0].affectedRows > 0) {
                    history.push("/backend/imagegallerylist");
                    showToast("Information!", "Gallery has been saved successfully.");
                }
                //return resultSet;
            } catch (e) {
                setLoader(false);
            }
        }
        setValidated(1);
    };

    const onAddSide = (e) => {
        debugger;
        let newImageList = [...list];
        if (row.Id && row.Id > 0) {
            if (newImageList && newImageList.length > 0) {
                const selectedIndex = newImageList.findIndex((item) => item.Id === row.Id);
                if (selectedIndex > -1) {
                    newImageList[selectedIndex] = row;
                }
            }
        } else {
            row.Id = Math.max.apply(
                Math,
                newImageList.map(function (o) {
                    return o.Id + 1;
                })
            );
            if (!row.Id || (row.Id && row.Id === 0) || row.Id === -Infinity) {
                row.Id = 1;
            }
            newImageList.push(row);
        }
        setList(newImageList);
        setImage("");
        setRow({
            ImageName: "",
            Name: "",
            ImageServerPath: "",
            ImageFullUrl: "",
            ImageUrl: "",
            SiteId: 1,
            CreatedBy: 1,
            CreatedOn: "",
            Id: 0,
            IsDeleted: 0,
            IsVisible: 1,
            ModifiedBy: 1,
            ModifiedOn: "",
        });
    };

    const onDeleteSlide = (e) => {
        //debugger;
        const dataToShow = list ? list.filter((item) => item.Id.toString() !== e.target.id) : list;
        setList(dataToShow);
    };

    const onEditSlide = (e) => {
        // debugger;
        if (list && list.length > 0) {
            const selectedIndex = list.findIndex((item) => item.Id.toString() === e.target.id);
            if (selectedIndex > -1) {
                setRow(list[selectedIndex]);
            }
        }
    }; 
   
    const onCropperZoomChange =(e) => {
        if(e && e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.value)
        {
            let lZoomValue =  e.currentTarget.value;
            if(lZoomValue && lZoomValue < 0.4)
            {
                //setZoom(0.28);
                setZoom(0.4);
            }
            else if(lZoomValue && lZoomValue > 1)
            {
                setZoom(1);
            }
            else{
                setZoom(lZoomValue);
            }          
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <Page breadcrumb={breadcrumb} pageName={pageName} fluid>
            <form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={HandleSaveMenu} className="user-form">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <TitleBar title="Edit Gallery" />
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <div className="form-row">
                            <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="Name">
                                    Name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    name="Name"
                                    required
                                    id="Name"
                                    className={`form-control ${nameError ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
                                    value={detail.Name}
                                    onChange={handleFormChanges}
                                />
                                {nameError ? <div className="invalid-feedback">{nameError}</div> : ""}
                                {!nameError && <div className="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>}
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ImageCropWidth">
                                    Width
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    name="ImageCropWidth"
                                    id="ImageCropWidth"
                                    className={`form-control`}
                                    value={imageCropWidth}
                                    onChange={(e) => setImageCropWidth(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ImageCropWidth">
                                    Height
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    name="ImageCropWidth"
                                    id="ImageCropWidth"
                                    className={`form-control`}
                                    value={imageCropHeight}
                                    onChange={(e) => setImageCropHeight(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label className="form-label">&nbsp;</label>
                                <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
                                    <input
                                        id="IsVisible"
                                        name="IsVisible"
                                        checked={detail.IsVisible}
                                        onChange={handleFormChanges}
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        className="custom-control-input"
                                    />
                                    <label title="" htmlFor="IsVisible" className="custom-control-label">
                                        Active
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <SingleGalleryRow
                            data={row}
                            setRow={setRow}
                            onUpload={singlefileSelectedHandler}
                            onAddSide={onAddSide}
                            IsDisabled={IsDisabled}
                        />

                        <ul className="slide-list">
                            {list &&
                                list.map(function (item, i) {
                                    //debugger;
                                    return (
                                        <li key={i}>
                                            <div className="slide-row">
                                                <div className="img-holder">
                                                    <img
                                                        className="thumbnail"
                                                        src={item.ImageFullUrl}
                                                        alt={item.ImageName}
                                                        onClick={() => showImageForCrop(item)}
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="btns-holder">
                                                    <button
                                                        type="button"
                                                        id={item.Id}
                                                        onClick={onDeleteSlide}
                                                        className="btn btn-circle btn-sm btn-danger"
                                                    >
                                                        <MdDelete />
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </ul>
                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer>
                        <div className="btn-holder text-right">
                            <Button type="submit" variant="primary" disabled={isSubmitClicked}>
                                Save
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Card.Footer>
                </Card>
            </form>
            <CenteredPopup
                show={umodalShow}
                onHide={() => setUModalShow(false)}
                title="Crop Image"
                content=""
                closetext="Close"
                savetext="Apply"
                onSaveChanges={onSaveImage}
            >
                <div className="cropimage-container"> 
                <div className="cropimage-tools">                
                <span className="cropimage-icons"                       
                        onClick={(e) => setCropShape('rect')}                       
                        >
                         <MdOutlineCrop /> 
                         <span className="cropimage-text">
                             Crop
                          </span>   
                        </span>
                        <span  className="cropimage-icons"                   
                        onClick={(e) => setCropShape('round')} >
                            <MdOutlineCircle /> 
                            <span className="cropimage-text">
                            Circle
                          </span>   
                        </span>
                </div>                        
                <div className="crop-container">
                    <Cropper
                        image={Image}
                        crop={crop}                          
                        cropSize={cropSize}
                        cropShape={cropShape}
                        zoom={zoom || 1}
                        showGrid={true}
                        zoomWithScroll={false}
                        objectFit="horizontal-cover"
                        onCropChange={setCrop}                           
                        onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
                        onZoomChange={onCropperZoomChange}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row ic_rangeslider">
                <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ZoomBtn">
                        {zoom  || 1}
                    </label>
                    <span className="range-slider__wrap">                          
                     <input
                        id="zoomrangeid"
                        type="range"
                        className="slider range-slider range-slider--light"
                        value={zoom  || 1}
                        min={0.4}
                        max={1}
                        step={0.1}
                        aria-labelledby="Zoom" 
                        onChange={onCropperZoomChange}                                                     
                        /> 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </CenteredPopup>
    </Page>
);
```

}

export default withRouter(EditImage);

I am trying to fix it from four hours by reading through the articles from google.
I don't want the page to be reloaded/refreshed.  My image files are being uploaded successfully and my node js service is returning the result in json.

[image]

If you need anything, please ask.
Why my browser is being reloaded/refreshed when my fileUpload is complete?

```
My client package.json
{
    "name": "test1",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "faker": "^5.5.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-easy-crop": "^4.0.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",          
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.0",                    
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",           
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },       
    },      
}
```

Comment: Could you also put a code of your component that does the uploading?

Comment: Do you want the html part or complete code of a component?

Comment: Well. it would be good to see form part of this html structure, to see what is going on. Also, have you tried to place e.prventDefault not in reader.onload = (e) => { but after const fileUpload = (e) => {?

Comment: Ok check now. the text limit has been completed. so thats' why i had to remove some content.